# Odoo controllers avoid json-rpc when type="json"

Tags: odoo

I've the following route:

```
@http.route([
    '/whatever/create'
], auth="none", type='json', methods=['POST'], csrf=False)
```

which I'm using to send a post request with json data on its body.

Is there any way to avoid using json-rpc responses on routes of `type="json"`? I would like to just answer plain json.

If it is not possible, is there any way to get the json data placed on the body request by using `type="http"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@http.route('/whatever/create', auth='public', methods=['POST'], type='http')
 def index(self, **kw):
    data = request.httprequest.data
    return 'success'
```

Above code defined in Odoo

```
url = "http://localhost:8069/whatever/create"

param = {
    "type_operation": "PTI",
    "label": "",
}
headers = {'Content-type': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(param), headers=headers)
```

Above code i have requested from a py file

While sending request you should change Content-type

```
'Content-type': 'application/json' --- > 'Content-type': 'text/plain'
```

Also while returning it only accept String

```
return {'status': 'success'} ---> return 'success'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, when doing this the following error message appears: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'http' but called with a request of type 'json'

Comment: I have updated the answer please check it and let me know

Comment: Thanks, I won't use this workaround but thanks for the solution.